# Lookup product category from UPC Code

Tags: web-services

Is there a way to get a product's category from its UPC code?

For instance I want to use the upc code to determine if a food item is, frozen food, dairy bread, alcohol, etc...

Is there a web service that will do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) doesn't say anything about UPC containing any product category number. The UPC just consists of a global manufacturer number and article number.

As [upcdata.info](http://upcdata.info) categories are user-generated, not every product is contained in a category or products are categorized differently (e.g. "oregano" could be categorized as "spice", although there is a category "italian spices").

My approach to categorizing products by EAN/UPC:

I had the same problem, but instead trying to get low-quality category data from a web service I just pulled manufacturer information from [GEPIR](http://gepir.gs1.org/v31/xx/gtin.aspx?Lang=en-US) (which is the official registrar for EAN and GLN, also works with UPC numbers).

As I noticed that big companies like Nestlé, Procter&Gamble etc. have separate number ranges for different product (sub-)categories, I just try to identify those ranges and assign the appropriate category.

On the other hand, if I know that a manufacturer only has products of one category (e.g. spices), I can assign all products of that manufacturer to the "spices" category.

Despite of this automatic approach, there's still much work to do in order to get **every** product categorized intelligently.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can make a quick mashup using: searchupc.com and upcdata.info and then retrieve product information from google product API.

Also, you can use AWSECommerceService API to retrieve something like this:

```
        ItemLookupRequest request = new ItemLookupRequest();
    request.getResponseGroup().add("Large");
    request.setIdType("UPC"); // TODO: need to change if it's EAC
    request.getItemId().add(upc);
    request.setSearchIndex("All");
```